# Linux crash when zeroing vmalloc area

Tags: linux, memory, module, linux-kernel, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm developing an LKM and I'm zeroing an vmalloc'ed area of 8192 bytes after alloc it. I know I can use vzalloc(), but it confuses me, why if I do:

```
pmem = vmalloc(8192);
ret = safe_zero(pmem, 8192);
```

when it's over the 2nd page, the VM crashes. I mean it becomes blocked. The SSH session disconnects and I must reboot.
I don't understand why.

The `safe_zero` function is:

```
int safe_readwrite(void *dst, void *src, size_t len) {
    size_t i = 0;
    char *cdst = dst, *csrc = src;

    pagefault_disable();
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        cdst[i] = csrc[i];
        if (cdst[i] != csrc[i]) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    pagefault_enable();
    return 0;
}

int safe_zero(void *dst, size_t len) {
    char zero = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    char *cdst = dst;

    for(; i < len; i++) {
        //pinfo("writing %d byte(s) at %p\r", sizeof(zero), &cdst[i]);
        ret = safe_readwrite(&cdst[i], &zero, sizeof(zero));
        if (ret != 0) {
            return ret;
        }
    }
    //pinfo("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking that has no sense the error. And I tested to do an pseudo-sleep by doing iterations. The problem is after the zero. I am using sys_write to print into stdout, and seems it crashes before is transmitted over SSH.

Sorry. That wasn't happening before switching from discrete to integrated GPU.